# How can I place a value at a certain place in a xsl table?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have two xml files, one with currencies and another with countries.

Sample of country.xml:

```
<root>
    <row>
       <CountryName>Denmark</CountryName>
       <CountryCode>DNK</CountryCode>
       <Year>2016</Year>
       <Value>5731118</Value>
    </row>
    <row>
       Another country...
    </row>
</root>
```

Sample of currencies.xml:

```
<valuta>
    <overskrift>Valutaliste</overskrift>
    <oppdatert>30.10.2017 09:00</oppdatert>
    <timestamp>2017-10-30-09.18.29.485970</timestamp>
    <valutakurs>
         <land>USA</land>
         <isokode>US</isokode>
         <kode>USD</kode>
         <enhet>1</enhet>
         <navn>Dollar</navn>
     </valutakurs>
     <valutakurs>
         Another currency...
     </valutakurs>
</valuta>
```

I have merged every line of `<kode></kode>` from my currencies.xml with country.xml so now I got everything I need in one xml file.

So I was wondering if I could place for example DKK at the same row as Denmark only using xsl?

Or can I do this with php and merge them into right place to begin with?

This is what I got so far.:

[image: This is what I got so far.]

What I want is to fill this table with the currencies, but they need to be in the right place.

EDIT:

XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:key name = "year-search" match = "row" use = "Year"/>

<xsl:variable name="landkoder">NOR,SWE,DNK,FRO,FIN,ISL,GRL</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Nordic Countries</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Country</th>
        <!--<th>Country Code</th>
        <th>Year</th>-->
        <th>Population</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select = "key('year-search', '2016')">
      <xsl:if test="contains($landkoder, CountryCode)">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="CountryName"/></td>
          <!--<td><xsl:value-of select="CountryCode"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Year"/></td>-->
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Result(Sorry for Norwegian names on countries :P)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/932EP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a global variable or parameter `<xsl:param name="currency-codes" select="document('currencies.xml')/valuta/valutakurs"/>` and then inside of your `for-each` use e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="$currency-codes[land = current()/CountryName]/kode/>` where you want to output the relevant currency code. I hope I have read the input structures well and the comparison has to be between `land` and `CountryName`.

Comment: It works! Thanks! If I want to expand it to include all of Europe. What about Finland and other countries that uses Euro as currency?

Comment: That mainly depends on how your two input documents are structured and which data they contain exactly, so far you haven't shown enough of that to tell.

Comment: There isn't more data than I've shown in my samples. Just more countries and currencies using the same structure. No problem, I think I'm just gonna skip that for now. I'm gonna edit my question with result and accept solution ofc, thanks! :)